# ActiveRecord: Does destroy_all execute callbacks for associated records?

Tags: activerecord

I have four models:

```
class Order < WebDatabase
    has_many :shipments

class Shipment < WebDatabase
    belongs_to :order
    has_many :line_items, :order => "id", :dependent => :destroy

class LineItem < WebDatabase
    belongs_to :shipment
    has_many :line_item_messages, :dependent => :destroy

class LineItemMessage < WebDatabase
    belongs_to :line_item
```

So if I did `@order.shipments.destroy_all`, would there be a chain of destroys where `@order.shipments.line_items` are destroyed and `@order.shipments.line_items.line_item_messages` are destroyed too because of the :dependent => :destroy on each of the models?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

from the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) (emphasis is my own)

> ## destroy_all(conditions = nil)
>
> ### public
>
> Destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record and calling its destroy method. Each object’s callbacks are executed (including :dependent association options and before_destroy/after_destroy Observer methods). Returns the collection of objects that were destroyed; each will be frozen, to reflect that no changes should be made (since they can’t be persisted).
>
> Note: Instantiation, callback execution, and deletion of each record can be time consuming when you’re removing many records at once. It generates at least one SQL DELETE query per record (**or possibly more, to enforce your callbacks**). If you want to delete many rows quickly, without concern for their associations or callbacks, use delete_all instead.

Comment: if it helped, please check the answer so it's out of the "unanswered" queue :)